# Difficulty Rendering Partial from another View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am facing trouble rendering a partial in `Rails 4.2.1`. There are no errors in the Rails Server logs and also no output in the view. I have removed the `as:` option and the result is still the same. Even if I hardcode the partial, the view does not display the information and the server logs show no errors.

**app/views/registry_requests/_index.html.erb**

```
<p><%= request.vehicle.make %></p>
```

**app/views/users/_admin.html.erb**

```
<!-- Columns -->
<div class="row">
  <!-- Dashboard -->
  <%= render 'admin_panel' %>

  <!-- Body Content -->
  ...

    <!-- Widgets -->
    ...
          <%= render partial: "registry_requests/index", collection: @registry_requests, as: :request %>

        ...
      <!-- Blog Feed -->
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="admin-widget">
          <h1 class="widget">Recent Blog Posts</h1>
          ...
        </div>
        <a class="admin-widget-link" href="blog_create.html">Create Post</a>
      </div>
      <!-- Current Moderators -->
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="admin-widget">
          <h1 class="widget">Current Moderators</h1>
          ....
        </div>
        <a class="admin-widget-link" href="#">Manage Moderators</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**logs**

```
Started GET "/users/6" for ::1 at 2015-08-18 12:35:30 -0400
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"6"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]
  Rendered users/_admin_panel.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered registry_requests/_index.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered users/_admin.html.erb (3.8ms)
  Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (5.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 117ms (Views: 113.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

Comment: is `@registry_requests` defined in your `UsersController#show `?

Comment: @LuisMenjivar ...this completely escaped me. Thank you. Please submit your answer so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice!

make sure `@registry_requests` is defined in your `UsersController#show`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<% request.each do |one_request| %>
  <p><%= one_request.vehicle.make %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This provides no errors or information in the view. Also, since we are rendering a collection we should not have to loop inside the partial?

Answer (score 0):

You should try doing something like this:

In your **app/views/users/_admin.html.erb**

```
<% @registry_requests.each do |request| %>
  <%= render partial: "registry_requests/index", :locals => {:registry_request => request} %>
<% end %>
```

**app/views/registry_requests/_index.html.erb**

```
<p><%= registry_request.vehicle.make %></p>
```

Since `@registry_requests` is a collection so you will have to iterate through it to get each record so that you can find each record's `make`.